# Eclipse Juno doesn't show SVN history

Tags: eclipse, svn, configuration

Usually when I click on any file or directory in package explorer (or any other explorer), the history view shows the whole SVN history of that directory. Unfortunately my history stays blank and I don't see any information. I didn't find any option in preferences too. Any ideas?

I'm using Juno, Subversive, SVNKit 1.3.8.

Comment: Did you enable the "Link with Editor and Selection" option (the button with the two arrows in the history view)?

Comment: I don't think that I have this button in that view at all. Otherwise I already would have tried it. But I will look at it again when I'm at home.

Comment: StefanFerstl is right. There must be this icon in the view toolbar. Maybe you are in the wrong view if not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to right click on the file/folder and select `Team` -> `Show history`.

To let the view refresh itself depending on your selection, select the `Link with Editor and Selection` icon in the view toolbar:

[image]

Comment: You were right, I forgot that I have to execute Team -> Show history. I though it would work by just displaying the history view.